# UIView layer not masking correctly

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer

I'd like to create a UIView that has rounded corners on the top left and top right.

In order to do that, i'd like to mask the UIView with a CAShapeLayer.

This is the code I am using:

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.menuContainerView.bounds
                                               byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight
                                                     cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(20.0, 20.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = self.menuContainerView.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

self.menuContainerView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

however, when i run this code, it appears that the mask has no effect. Any ideas why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did not mention in my answer is that I was also setting the same maskLayer as the mask to another view (one offscreen). Apparently you can't do this.... i removed that extra line

```
self.otherContainerView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

and it worked as desired.

Comment: For masking, a path can only be used on one view. If you wanted it on multiple views you can just remake the path (even using the same variable) and then add that to the other view. I found this out the hard way as well.